# GStreamer Videomixer Raspivid

Tags: camera, raspberry-pi, gstreamer, stereoscopy

I have searched all over the place and have not found anyone using the videomixer function from gstreamer with the raspberry pi's raspivid.

I am trying to duplicate the raspivid output and merge them side by side and then eventually send a stream over tcp. But for right now I am just looking for some help with getting the videomixing to work.

The resulting video should be 1280x568 for my specific application and I do not care that there is any angle between the videos to create a "3d effect" because it is not required for the specific application I'm making.

I am using gstreamer 1.2 so the function call is gst-launch-1.0 and I can not use ffmpeg b/c I believe it has depricated, so I assume I would just use videoconvert to achieve the same result.

Im not sure if I should be using h264parse instead of decodebin. So here is what Ive got so far:
`gst-launch-1.0 fdsrc | raspivid -t 0 -h 568 -w 640 -fps 25 -hf -b 2000000 -o - ! decodebin ! queue ! videoconvert ! videobox border-alpha=0 right=-640 ! videomixer name=mix  ! videoconvert ! autovideosink fdsrc | raspivid -t 0 -h 568 -w 640 -fps 25 -hf -b 2000000 -o - ! decodebin ! queue ! videoconvert ! videobox border-alpha=0 left=-640 ! mix.`

Im trying to model this based off these two sources(the raspivid command in the first link works for me):
http://www.raspberry-projects.com/pi/pi-hardware/raspberry-pi-camera/streaming-video-using-gstreamer
http://www.technomancy.org/gstreamer/playing-two-videos-side-by-side/

I know I am probably so far off but I am having a lot of difficulty finding examples of how to do this, especially with the raspivid function. I would greatly appreciate any help. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a exemple, with some explaination how to use videomixer [using videomixer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19678956/combine-multiple-image-files-using-videomixer-gstreamer/19684914#19684914)

Answer (score 0):

Example of using videomixer combining 3 videos
Note: UNIX paths are used in this example

```sh
gst-launch-1.0 -e \
videomixer name=mix background=0 \
        sink_1::xpos=0   sink_1::ypos=0 \
        sink_2::xpos=200 sink_2::ypos=0 \
        sink_3::xpos=100 sink_3::ypos=100 \
    ! autovideosink \
uridecodebin uri='file:///data/big_buck_bunny_trailer-360p.mp4' \
    ! videoscale \
    ! video/x-raw,width=200,height=100  \
    ! mix.sink_1 \
uridecodebin uri='file:///data/sintel_trailer-480p.webm' \
    ! videoscale \
    ! video/x-raw,width=200,height=100  \
    ! mix.sink_2 \
uridecodebin uri='file:///data/the_daily_dweebs-720p.mp4' \
    ! videoscale \
    ! video/x-raw,width=200,height=100  \
    ! mix.sink_3
```